# Extract file thumbnail from mp4 file

Tags: video, mp4, mkv, thumbnails

I'm currently converting a few mp4 file to mkv. In the process they lose their file thumbnails and I wanted to keep them. So I'm searching for a way to extract the custom thumbnails from the mp4 files before converting them. To clarify the thumbnails are not scenes from the mp4 but custom made ones that were copied into the mp4.